# Euclidean distance between two points with coordinates stored as strings

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to find the Euclidean distance between two points. I have the concatenated coordinates in a single cell. Each set of coordinates is like `(x1,y1,z1)` and `(x2,y2,z2)`.

How can I do this in Excel?

Comment: You say the coordinates are concatenated. Does that mean you have the x, y, and z coordinates in separate cells somewhere else in the workbook?

Comment: Based on your comment on kazoni's answer, it sounds like your question isn't about Euclidean distance, it's about how to parse the comma delimited coordinates.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, i need to use them in separate like in euclidean distance formula

Answer (score 1):

Try the following User Defined Function *(UDF)*:

```
Public Function distance(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Double
    Dim zum As Double, i As Long
    ary1 = Split(s1, ",")
    ary2 = Split(s2, ",")

    zum = 0
    For i = 0 To 2
        zum = zum + (CDbl(ary1(i)) - CDbl(ary2(i))) * (CDbl(ary1(i)) - CDbl(ary2(i)))
    Next i

    distance = Sqr(zum)
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=distance(A1,A2)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Here is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`=sqrt(power(x2-x1,2)+power(y2-y1,2)+power(z2-z1,2))`

Or as the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) states:

[image: Euclidean Distance Formula for 3 Dimentions]

**Edit:**  Saw after the fact that you had concatenated cells.  That complicates things a bit.  If you can separate the 3 parts of each coordinates, this is trivial.  Otherwise, I need to know a little more about what range of numbers we may be talking about?  (I'm thinking of a little `=left() =mid() =right` magic.)

Comment: I know the formula what i asked is how to apply this formula for two concatenated cells in excel

Comment: Are your cells set up like point 1 is [3] [5] [7] and point 2 is [4] [8] [12] or is it [3,5,7] [4,8,12]?

Comment: like [3,5,7] ,[1,2,3]

Comment: the range of every co-ordinate is 1 to 5

Comment: Ok, then you can get away with something like this (assume x1 is cell A1, x2 is cell A2):
  
`=sqrt(power(left(A2,1)-left(A1,1),2) + power(mid(A2,3,1)-mid(A1,3,1),2) + power(right(A2,1)-right(A1,1),2))`

Comment: I tried but it is not working

Comment: [Here's what I did.](http://imgur.com/9ieTY4z)